# Adding to inherited C# Class XML Elements

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance, serialization

Is there any way to Add to child classes in an inherited Class?  I have a huge class file that I've ran through an XSD to class file generator.  I'd rather not have to manually edit the generated file each time an update is made to the XSD file.  Is there any way I can inherit all members of the generated file and add to its child classes?

Example:  If I wanted to add string Child_String2 how could I do this?

```
   File1.cs
    namespace test
    {
        class AutoGenerated
        {
            string Parent_string { get; set; }
            public class Child
            {
                string child_string1 { get; set; }
                //I want to add string Child_String2 {get;set;} at this level in to ModifiedParent from file "MyAttempt.cs"
            }
        }
    }

   MyAttempt.cs
   namespace test
   {
       class ModifiedParent: Parent
       {
        Child.string child_string2{get;set;} 
       }
   }
```

This obviously does not work, but the intention is to add child_string2 to the Child class inside of Parent.

Is there any way to accomplish something like this?

The original reason of this question was because I needed to serialize/deserialize to a class that I am adding to.  If I were to inherit just from "Child", I am able to assign my modified "Child" inside of "Parent" but the serializer then has an issue as it does not expect child_string2.

Any tips, suggestions or even links to solving this myself would be appreciated.

Edit:
So after discussion with coworkers and searching around online it sounds like we haven't been able to come up with any direct solution. Unfortunately it sounds like the best approach would just be to edit the Generated CS file.  I do have access to the generator so I decided best approach would be to add a few lines to the generator to make the appropriate changes each time it is generated.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question but where is child_string2 generated?

Comment: Create you own schema the supplements the schema you already have.

Comment: child_string2 I was hoping to add at the same level as child_string1.  So the final object of ModifiedParent would contain Parent_string and a Child element.  Child Element would then contain child_string1 and child_string2.

Comment: So after discussion with coworkers and searching around online it sounds like we haven't been able to come up with any direct solution.  Unfortunately it sounds like the best approach would just be to edit the Generated CS file.  However I do have access to the generator so I decided best approach would be to add a few line to the generator to make the appropriate changes.